# Tidal forces in 3d space

Tags: tidal-effect

I'm trying to build a representation of the Tidal Forces of Earth using WebGL.

The image i'm using as reference is this one:

[image: Tidal Force representation]

I could achieve good results, for my purpose, on the XY, YZ and XZ planes only:
[image: Images generated in my program]

However, I could not combine the vectors into a single vector in the 3D space.

How can I find the "Tidal Force 3d vector"?

PS: Already tried to combine the vectors, but couldn't achieve what i'm hoping to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In this post I use bold face to denote triples of real numbers. That is, points in 3D space, with ${\bf x}=(x,y,z)$)

With a moon mass $m_m$ position ${\bf x}_m$, the vector force on your surface element mass $dm$ position $\bf x$, is $$G (dm) m_m\frac{ {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}}{\| {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}\|^3}$$

so it accelerates as the following if you ignore the gravitational effect of Earth:

$$G m_m\frac{ {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}}{\| {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}\|^3}$$

The acceleration of the Earth (whose center is at position ${\bf x}_e$) due to the moon is:

$$Gm_m\frac{ {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}_e}{\| {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}_e\|^3}$$

(a consequence of the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) and the equal/opposite forces law)

in the non-inertial frame of reference where the center of the Earth is stationary, the acceleration of the surface element is the difference of these two accelerations.

$$G m_m\left(\frac{ {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}}{\| {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}\|^3}-\frac{ {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}_e}{\| {\bf x}_m-{\bf x}_e\|^3}\right)$$

Physicists like to then do series expansions and what-not to find the two-lump pattern or come up with nicer expressions, but you don't need to do that.

If you know OpenGL, you probably can agree that this is really trivial vector math! If you plan on doing more of these demonstrations, try to solve them yourself using vector math first.

Comment: Aside: It's better to use the moon's gravitational parameter $\mu_m=4902.7988\pm0.0006$ km<sup>3</sup>/s<sup>2</sup> rather than $\mu_m=G\,m_m$. Conceptually, the two are the same. In practice, it's $\mu_m$ that's observed.

Comment: Hello. I made a huge progress in my program with these calculations and dropped the old ones. However, before marking this as the accepted answer, please take a look at the program [here](http://daed-dev.on.br/astro/mares) (Pressing the eye button enables camera control. Using the slider on the left it is possible to exaggerate the ocean scale). I added the Sun tidal force as well (ratio 1, while using 2.2 for the Moon). I can see the neap and spring tides, but I would rather check on your opinions before saying it is correct now.